# Sequence both converging and diverging?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I have the sequence sum 1 to infinity of 10^n/n!

If I plug it into symbollab, it says it converges by the ratio test.
If I plug it into wolfram alpha, it says it diverges by geometric series test.

Which is it ?!

Comment: It definitely converges. If you post the link to your query of Wolfram Alpha, we might be able to help diagnose what's gone wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the ratio test, it converges. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right| = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{10^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\times\frac{n!}{10^{n}} = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{10}{n+1} = 0 < 1
\end{align*}

Which entry did you put at the WA website?

Answer (score 0):

That sum is
$e^{10}-1$,
so it definitely converges.